# Shallow copy not crashing

Tags: c++

While going into C++ in depth, I am working on shallow/deep copying. According to the MOOC I'm following, the following code should crash,

```
// .hpp file

#ifndef _COPY_HPP_
#define __COPY_HPP_


class Shallow { 
    
    private:
    
     int* data;

    public:
      
        void setData (int d){ *data = d;}
        int getData(){ return *data;}  
        
        // constructor
        Shallow (int d);

        // copy constructor
        Shallow(const Shallow &source);

        //destructor
        ~Shallow();

   
};

#endif



// .cpp file
#include "copy.hpp"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

Shallow::Shallow(int d){

    data = new int;
    *data = d;
}

void displayShallow(Shallow s){
    cout << "displayShallow: " << s.getData() << "\n";

}

Shallow::Shallow(const Shallow &source)
    : data{source.data} {
        cout << "copy constructor call" << "\n";
    }


Shallow::~Shallow(){
    delete data;
    cout << "freeing data" << "\n";

}


int main(){

    Shallow original{100};
    cout << original.getData() << "\n";

    // destructor called after this call
    displayShallow(original);

    cout << original.getData() << "\n";

    original.setData(29);

    cout << original.getData() << "\n";

    return 0;


}
```

as (into `displayShallow()`) "*the destructor is called and the destructor releases the storage it is pointing to in the heap. The object that was copied into this function still points to this now released storage but it thinks that the storage is valid so all kinds of bad things can happen.*"

When the "teacher" runs this code, his program crashes while I get:

```
100
copy constructor call
displayShallow: 100
freeing data
0
29
freeing data
```

It seems that the storage to which `data` points to is set to `0` instead of crashing. Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: "Undefined Behaviour" means "it may crash, it may not crash, it may unleash the wrath of [nasal demons](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)"

Comment: *According to the MOOC* -- What is "MOOC"?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie "massive online open course", basically a programming class.

Comment: Well, that's another online C++ course giving out erroneous information.

Comment: you are not guaranteed to get a crash, what would be the use of such a guarantee?

Comment: It is common misunderstanding that invoking UB in C++ will mandatory lead to crash. Unfortunately it is not the case. That would be nice but it will cost and C++ has paradigm - do not pay for what you do not use.

Comment: `#ifndef _COPY_HPP_  #define __COPY_HPP_` -- This is wrong in so many ways, unless this is a typo.

Comment: The compiler's not obligated to do extra work to overwrite memory that's being deallocated, change the OS/CPU memory access permissions so further attempted access will fail, etc. - though it could if it cared to - it's more than that memory may at any time be reallocated for some other purpose, then overwritten with the content that purpose requires, so any assumption that the original memory content will be there could be invalidated at some point in time.  For undefined behaviours, you simply have to avoid them, not pretend to be reasoning about when they'll bite.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: except the extra underscore what are these "so many ways"?

Comment: Identifiers with leading underscores are reserved for the system implementation.  [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: Ok, I will keep this in mind in the future.